# Can I use subqueries in a 'containable' condition?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, subquery, max, containable

In my CakePHP I have ModelA which hasMany ModelB. ModelB has an int value Q.

Can I query ModelA and use containable to ensure that only those ModelB records with the maximum value for Q?

I've tried this:

```
$this->ModelA->contain(array(
    'ModelB.Q =(SELECT MAX(ModelB.Q) FROM modelb ModelB WHERE ModelA_id = ' . $id . ')'
));
```

But it throws a MySQL error because CakePHP interprets the right hand side of that equality operator as a field (at least I think that's why) and so dots it.

```
... WHERE `Draw`.`round` =.(SELECT MAX.(`Draw`.`round`) ...
```

Is there a way to do this? I'd prefer not to have to drop down into `$query()` mode, if at all possible.

---

**EDIT** OK, after trying to follow the advice on the page that api55 suggested, I have this code:

```
$dbo = $this->Tournament->getDataSource();
$conditionsSubQuery['"Draw"."tournament_id"'] = $id;
$maxRounds = $dbo->buildStatement(array(
    'fields' => array('MAX(Draw.round) AS prevRound'),
    'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this->Tournament->Draw),
    'alias' => 'Draw',
    'limit' => null,
    'offset' => null,
    'joins' => array(), 
    'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
    'order' => null,
    'group' => null
    ),
    $this->Tournament
);
$maxSubQuery = ' "Draw"."round" = (' . $maxRounds . ') ';
$maxSubQueryExpression = $dbo->expression($maxSubQuery);
$this->Tournament->contain(array(
    'Entrant.selected = 1',
    $maxSubQueryExpression
));
$tournament = $this->Tournament->read(null, $id);
```

But when it runs, it gives me 7 notice/warnings. The first 6 are to do with an object being passed instead of a string:

> preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

And 6 variations on this:

> Object of class stdClass to string conversion

The last is less clear:

> Model "Tournament" is not associated with model ""

I suspect I'm being colossally stupid, but there we go.

Comment: The contain uses conditions as a normal find, a subquery can be generated and put in conditions. So you should be able to do this as well. Try the subquery part in [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions) and tell me how did it go ;) (i mean to generate conditions and use conditions=>$conditions in the contain)

Comment: @api55 You again! My hero! You should probaby put that as an answer, so that I can mark it as correct if I need to.

Comment: can you look at the stacktrace of the notice/warning and tell us which line is calling the error.... is a snowball effect, the first warnings generate the secod ones and the las one. i think this line is the faulty one $dbo = $this->Tournament->getDataSource(); with this one  'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this->Tournament->Draw), also i suggest find('first',...) instead of read...

Comment: It turns out that all but the last of the problems described above were indeed caused by one error. Instead of `$maxSubQueryExpression` it is necessary to use `$maxSubQueryExpression->value`. Still struggling to get it to use the right model though. I think the problem is with this line: `$maxSubQuery = ' "Draw"."round" = (' . $maxRounds . ') ';` The error is now `Model "Tournament" is not associated with model " "Draw""`

Comment: I've tried fiddling around with the way in which `Draw.round` is specified, but every way seems to lead to some sort of error.

Comment: ok, two stupid questions, 1) are you doing it in the model or in the controller? 2) does tournament have any association done with draw (hasMany, belongsTo, HABTM) ?? If is IN the model, you may try loading the model by force (in controller is loadModel('Model') )  and try $this->Draw directly instead of $this->Tournament

Comment: I'm doing this in the controller. The Tournament model hasMany draw and the Draw model belongsTo Tournament.

Comment: and where exactly is the error ocurring? which line?? this one: $tournament = $this->Tournament->read(null, $id);?

Answer (score 0):

The contain uses conditions as a normal find, a subquery can be generated and put in conditions. So you should be able to do this as well. Try the subquery part in [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions) and tell me how did it go ;)

This way of generating subqueries for conditions shouldn't fail :D since is the cakephp way.
If you got an error or something comment the answer to see if i can help.

Comment: It's a bit long winded, but I've put my attempt in an edit. (Along with the errors it causes.)